# Monit Syntax Error

Tags: monit

I am using Monit v5.5 and trying to set a check for apache. Everything below is as per the documentation. However, when i say `monit -t`, i get `/etc/monit.conf:155: Error: syntax error 'http'` which points to the HTTP HEADERS line. Commenting it out works fine. Same issue with `content = "WrongPath"`. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

```
check host mysite with address mysite.com
    start program = "/usr/sbin/httpd start"
    stop program = "/usr/sbin/httpd stop"
    if failed port 80 protocol http
       with http headers [Host: mysite.com, Cache-Control: no-cache]
       and request "/pingtest.html" with content = "WrongPath"
    then restart
    if 5 restarts within 10 cycles then timeout
```

Comment: try the latest version 5.11

Answer (score 1):

Your version is too old, `HTTP HEADERS` feature is in version 5.9. Please read [this](http://mmonit.com/monit/changes/).